# How to make a Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu open by default when it is viewed using mobile

Tags: html, css

I cant post it on fiddle. because the problem cannot be recreated there.

Please take a look at my site (open it in "MOBILE" or RESIZE your browser to make it similar like mobile view):

=> [my site](http://feednews.id)

if you resize correctly you will see the menu icon (3line icon) on the top left side.

When you click 3line icon you will see "category" menu. then when you click arrow icon you will see "sub category" menu. My visitor will need to click twice just to see the "sub category"

How to make it just 1 click. so if visitor click 3line icon the "subcategory" dropdown is opened by default.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you create the menu, with some JS library, framework, content management system or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Media queries` and select your `CSS Selector` for your `Element` then use `display: block;`

for example

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
    .dropdown-menu {
       display: block;
    }
 }
```

https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that: [Bootstrap nav bars examples](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/navbars/)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your website, you'll notice when a 'category' gets expanded, what's happening is the class 'mm-opened' is added to the list item. And from my testing, it seems that the 'mm-opened' class has no effect when on a larger screen (because the mobile nav is its own element). So you should be able to just modify your HTML by adding the class 'mm-opened' to your category items:

So modifying your html inside the 'mobile side nav' element like this will cause a category be expanded by default:

```
<ul class="mm-listview mm-first mm-last">
   <li class="mm-vertical mm-opened">
   .....
   </li>
```

Comment: you are really my hero.. bing thanks to you. i have been trying to solve this for days. can you teach me how do you find the solution?

Comment: Glad it helped! I used the chrome dev tools and looked at the behavior of the elements when toggling the expand/collapse arrows. I just right click -> inspected one of the category elements on the page to get to the relevant portion of the DOM.